# What is the difference of sudo bash and sudo command in bash file?

Tags: bash

I would like to append some commands to ${HOME}/.bashrc file.

I made a script to do it.

```
# file name : setup_bash
bashrc_path="${HOME}/.bashrc"
comment="test"
sudo echo "${comment}" >> "${bashrc_path}"
```

and run it by

```
bash setup_bash
```

And it results in an error.

```
setup_bash: line 19: /home/user/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

line 19 is at (sudo echo ...).

Next I tried the following code,

```
sudo bash setup_bash
```

It results in success.

What is the difference of them? Please teach me it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shell i/o redirection happens *before* a command executes.  That is, when you run...

```
sudo echo "some text" >> /some/path
```

...the shell opens `/some/path` for input before it ever runs the `echo` command.  The implication of this is that the i/o redirection is *not* going to be affected by the `sudo` command (because the redirection happens *before `sudo` even runs*).  On the other hand, when you run...

```
sudo bash setup_bash
```

...you are running the *entire script* as the root user, which means that when it comes time to perform the i/o redirection the script is already running as `root` and so the redirection will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in

```
sudo echo "${comment}" >> "${bashrc_path}"
```

the shell (STDOUT) redirection (write -- append) operation `>> "${bashrc_path}"` is done first by the shell, as the user invoking user, this is done even before the main command is executed. And presumably the invoking user has no permission to open the file for writing, hence the permission denied error message from shell; this is irrespective of the command `sudo echo ...` because that command has not been started executing even by then.

Now when you used `sudo` at invocation time you are impersonating `root` (default) so the redirection -- write (append) operation would succeeed, (and as you might have guessed you don't even need the `sudo` in front of `echo` now).